# Why is is this click event handler not executing my code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi while learning html and css I got the idea of adding an scroll to top arrow to my page, I found an solution and adapted it to my project, but the javascript part is not working as I thought and I really don't know how to fix this.

I have following html-code for the arrow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- meta information -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>First Page</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@200;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts for Webfonts and Icons -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9dfc4870d4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
    //more elements...
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the javascript code which is located in the script.js file

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
$('#return-to-top').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0
    }, 500);
});
```

The fadeIn/fadeOut functions are executed correctly on my page but when I click the link nothing is happening or at least it's not jumping to the top of the page.

But if I use the internal script-element to place the code at the end of the body section of my html file it does all work correctly, but why isn't the click working as intended if I place this code in a external file is it because of loading order in the html file?

---

Comment: Because the script is executing before the `#return-to-top` element is in the DOM. One easy way to fix this is to include the whole `<script>` tag at the very end of the `body`. In other words, `<body> All your HTML content here <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script></body>`

Comment: Okay, thank you. What would I need to do if I wanted to keep the <script> tag in the <head> tag? Do I need to add an event listener for DOMContentLoaded or something like that to my code?

Comment: Try just using the `defer` attribute: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js" defer></script>`

Comment: Alright, it's working thank you.

Comment: Cool! I added an official response, can you upvote/mark as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `defer` attribute on your `script` to defer execution until the `body` loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js" defer></script>
```